# Magento2 - Track this Shipment navigates to a blank page

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipment-tracking

When I add a tracking number to an order and then click "track this shipment" in magento2, a blank page (domain.com/shipping/tracking/popup) pops up saying "Shipment #000000001".
How can I actually make this "track this shipment" work and actually show the tracking?
thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the APIs on the backend in order for the tracking to work. For example, if you are using USPS - google "USPS APIs" and you need to register on their website under "Developer".

When you register, they will send you an email with the API information you need to enter into the backend of Magento under Shipping Methods -> USPS.

Then the tracking will work.